# Instantiating a class defined in a different file in java using IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ the file containing my main method is instantiating a class defined in a different file. In my program, in the file Table.java, I am instantiating an LinkedListDeque, defined in the LinnkedListDeque.java file. When I compile using GitBash, with the command `javac db/Table.java`, I get no error and the program compiles correctly. Now, when I try running the program using IntelliJ, I receive the error saying that the instantiation of LinkedListDeque can't be done. Particularly, I have the error "Cannot resolve symbol LinkedListDeque". Both of my files are inside the package `package db;` and this is the way I am instantiating LinkedListDeque. 
Does anyone how I could solve this issue?

Comment: The error is only when you run? Sounds like you are just editing text files and trying to run them as Java applications. You need to create an IntelliJ project, otherwise, I can't reproduce this

Comment: Make sure that you have all your source files in the project folder.

Comment: Can you please attach screenshot of your project environment?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using GitBash to compile your programs. You can simply use IDE **RUN** command to compile and run the project.

1. Create new project in Intellij Idea.
2. Create new package called db **inside src folder**
3. Put your java files within that package.
4. Use **RUN** button in the tool bar to run your application.

This will solve your problem.